# Store passwords securely in SQL Server for use with dynamic datasources - SSIS

Tags: security, ssis, passwords, sql-server-2014

We make heavy use of dynamic datasources. We retrieve server name and database names from a table in a SQL Server database. A package loops through the server names and database names and executes once for every server, for every database.

These values are then put into the `ServerName` and `InitalCatalog` fields of the dynamic connection. User and password are pre-defined (and therefore the same for every connection). I would like to fill the user + password from a table too but then I have to store the passwords as clear text in that table.

Is there a way to store the password encrypted in that table and decrypt it when I need to use it? Any person having access to the SSIS package is allowed to know the passwords but they should not be easily read from the table containing the connection strings.

All suggestions to handle this (f.e.  using different approaches)  are very much appreciated !

Comment: You have some thoughts about this in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845414/securely-storing-credentials-that-cant-be-encrypted

Comment: Can't you make a special user for this and give the proper rights on every server. You can even make an ssis proxy account for it and you do not have to expose its passwork anywhere.

Comment: @Ako: could you elaborate on that? The only connection between the machine executing the SSIS package and the SQL servers (mixture of SQL in VM's and Azure SQL) is an sql connection. None of the machines are joined in a network. How would I then setup a 'poxy account'?  Sounds very interesting.

Comment: So when you use integrated security normally the job will try execute the step under the account of the SQL Agent, that is not what you want. Proxy account is a replacement for the credentials for the SQL Agent account (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175834.aspx), also not helpfull in this case. I remember that on Windows 2000 we used a trick by creating same local accounts with identical username and passwords on all servers to overcome the SSO limitation, but I don't know if that still works.

Comment: @Ako Can you out this comment as the answer? So I can give you credit where it's due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can encrypt/decrypt a column. See Microsoft's walkthrough here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017

Best practice is to then create a view that decrypts the column and then grant user-level (i.e., SELECT, ALTER, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) access to the view only because the view must have the symmetric key to decrypt the data. Exposing the key can be a security vulnerability, so you want that locked down as much as possible. A view with limited user access is the best place to allow a key to be exposed (if there is ever a good place to expose a key, which there is not).

But, Ako is correct. Use integrated security.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred solution is to keep using integrated security.

Normally the job will try execute the step under the account of the SQL Agent, that is not what you want.

Proxy account is a replacement for the credentials for the SQL Agent account (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175834.aspx), also not helpfull in this case.

I remember that on Windows 2000 we used a trick by creating same local accounts with identical username and passwords on all servers to overcome the SSO limitation, it will probably work in your situation.