# How to store accesses in serverside

Tags: encryption, datastore

**Question 1**

I have server side script, which connects to different data storages (ex. website database, ip-telephony server, web-analyst api). I storage passwords, tokens and other access data for data storages on server. That script runs by cron every day, not by user request.

In realy, i have many such scripts and hundreds accesses. All of these data storages belog to different companies, data in storages is very important. If server will be hack, hacker gets all of these accesses and companies data.

How can i secure storage for all of these accesses?

**Question 2**

Script from first question saves information into database. That information have to see only client in browser, programmers or databes admininstrator haven't see saved information.

Is there any way to encrypt data from cron server script and decrypt it only on client side in browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securely storing credentials that can't be encrypted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845414/securely-storing-credentials-that-cant-be-encrypted)

Comment: Yes, it is. Well, it's a duplicate of your first question. Don't ask multiple questions in one "question".